# Error in adding 4th organization in to Hyperledger Fabric 2.0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to Fabric 2.0 and recently installed all samples and I was able to run test-network without an issue with 2 orgs. Then I followed the directory on addOrg3 to add 3rd organization and join the channel I created earlier.

Now the fun part came in when I wanted to add 4th organization. What I did was, I copied the addOrg3 folder and renamed almost everything in each file to represent 4th organization. I even assigned new PORT for this organization. However I am seeing the following error.

I've also added the following in Scripts/envVar.sh

export PEER0_ORG4_CA=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt

And added the following in envVarCLI.sh

```
   elif [ $ORG -eq 4 ]; then        
    CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org4MSP"        
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_ORG4_CA  
    CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org4.example.com:12051
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/organizations/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/users/Admin@.../msp
```

I have also added step1Org4.sh and step2Org4.sh basically following by following addOrg3's structure.

What steps do you follow to add additional organizations ? Please help.

**"No such container: Org4cli"**

**Sorry for the formatting since I wasn't able to put in to coding style but here is the output from running the command *"./addOrg4.sh up"***

**Add Org4 to channel 'mychannel' with '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb'

> Desktop/blockchain/BSI/fabric-samples/test-network/addOrg4/../../bin/cryptogen

```
##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
 
##########################################################
############ Create Org4 Identities ######################
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=org4-crypto.yaml --output=../organizations
org4.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x
 
Generate CCP files for Org4
Desktop/blockchain/BSI/fabric-samples/test-network/addOrg4/../../bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#######  Generating Org4 organization definition #########
##########################################################
+ configtxgen -printOrg Org4MSP
2020-05-29 13:33:04.609 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-05-29 13:33:04.617 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /Desktop/blockchain/BSI/fabric-samples/test-network/addOrg4/configtx.yaml
+ res=0
+ set +x
 
 
###############################################################
####### Generate and submit config tx to add Org4 #############
###############################################################
Error: No such container: Org4cli
ERROR !!!! Unable to create config tx **
```

Comment: Please feel free to format my terminal output if you found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In your addOrg4.sh have condition check like this:

```sh
CONTAINER_IDS=$(docker ps -a | awk '($2 ~ /fabric-tools/) {print $1}')
if [ -z "$CONTAINER_IDS" -o "$CONTAINER_IDS" == " " ]; then
  echo "Bringing up network"
  Org4Up
fi
```

If you already run `addOrg3.sh up`, CONTAINER_IDS alway have value (Example: `51b4ad60d812`). It is ContainerID of Org3cli. So function Org4Up will never call. Simple way is just comment code like this:

```sh
# CONTAINER_IDS=$(docker ps -a | awk '($2 ~ /fabric-tools/) {print $1}')
# if [ -z "$CONTAINER_IDS" -o "$CONTAINER_IDS" == " " ]; then
  echo "Bringing up network"
  Org4Up
# fi
```

It will bring up Org4cli you missing.

Answer (score 0):

First check the container is up or not and if it is up then I think the CLI where the command is executed is not bootstrapped with the Org4 details.

I have added the 4th Organization from the three Org Hyperledger Fabric Network .Firstly, you have to create the Org4-artifacts (Crypto.yaml and Org4 docker file including the Org4Cli) and then try to follow the manual (step by step) process to add the new Organization from the official documentation.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/channel_update_tutorial.html

Omit the process of editing scripts (step1 Org3.sh ...) because the workflow for adding the 4th or a new Org is slightly changed.So,you will spend a lot of time in just modifying the scripts. 
I will write an article to add a new Org (4th) on medium,will paste the link here too.